# get_option function

Tags: theme-development, array, options

I'm currently trying to make my own theme, but i'm not quite sure how the get_option() function works, because how come this..

```
echo get_option('show_header', 'sultenhest_theme_display_options');
echo get_option('sultenhest_theme_display_options')['show_header'];
```

..both returns 1 (but Dreamweaver doesnt like the second option). While

```
echo get_option('twitter', 'sultenhest_theme_social_options');
```

..simply returns 'sultenhest_theme_social_options', which is incorrect.

An option would be to define the array as such

```
$social_options = get_option( 'sultenhest_theme_social_options' );
```

and call it like this

```
echo $social_options['twitter'];
```

It returns the correct string, but it only works in the header.php (if the array is defined there) file and not in, e.g. footer.php.

---

UPDATE:
Following partly ialocin and Brad Dalton i came up with this solution, which works like a charm:

```
function sultenhest($option, $arg){
  $the_array = array();
  foreach( get_option('sultenhest_theme_'.$option) as $key => $item ){
    $the_array[$key] = $item;
  }
  return $the_array[$arg];
}
```

and echoing it out like this:

```
echo sultenhest('social_options', 'twitter') ? '<a href="' . sultenhest('social_options', 'twitter') . '">Twitter</a>' : '';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `get_option()` wrong, first variant, so take another look at the [`get_option()` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option). Basically you can't directly access an array element with the function, it just doesn't support it.

The second variant should be possible, but you need at least PHP 5.4 - if I'm not totally mistaken; I don't know anything about dreamweaver.

The reason why you can't access the variable everywhere you want is the variable scope, read up on it at the [PHP Manual: Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

The easiest thing I imagine is to do it the old fashion way, just make a function you can use. Exemplary like this:

```
function wpse_179693_echo_my_options_array_value() {
    $social_options = get_option( 'sultenhest_theme_social_options' );
    if ( isset( $social_options['twitter'] ) ) {
        echo $social_options['twitter'];
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_option('some_option')['some_key']` actually does work in php 5.4, it's called [array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html).